# Formulas in reporting

Tags: reporting, formula

I have a difficult report question, which I cannot seem to solve.
This is a report on opportunities. We have two product picklists, in which we choose our products for opportunities. We also record the product split, i.e. the percentage of the annual revenue belongs to that product.

We are now facing the following problem. I want to create a formula field, which describes the following:

```
IF (ISPICKVAL (Product1, 'XYZ', AnnualRev*ProductSplit1, (IF (Product2, 'XYZ', AnnualRev*ProductSplit2, AnnualRev))
```

So, I basically only want to calculate the product split for product XYZ, but that product could be either in picklist 1 or 2.
My problem is that I cannot seem to access the picklists in formula fields.

Do you know how I can create this kind of report in Salesforce?

Comment: When you say you only want to report for product XYZ, is that always the same product, or are there many products you want to split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this kind of calculation in the report. You will have to create the formula field on the Opportunity object.

On reports you can only do 'aggregate' kind of formulas, no record-specific logic.